# How do i modify a teechart series value?

Tags: c++builder, teechart

I created a simple Gantt chart with one Gantt bar:

```
AnsiString date1, date2;
date1 = "25/04/1990";
date2 = "15/05/1990";
Series1 = new TGanttSeries(this);
Series1->ParentChart= Chart1;
Series1->AddGantt(StrToDate(date1), StrToDate(date2), StrToFloat("12,0"), "Main Task");
```

And now I need to change the gantt bar value.  How do I do it? For example, instead of `date2` being `15/05/1990`, I want to change it to `25/05/1990`? It's very confusing. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why are you using `StrTo...()` functions to convert string literals? Don't do that. For `TDate` values, use `SysUtils.EncodeDate()` eg `EncodeDate(1990, 4, 25)`, etc.  For floating point numbers, just use numeric literals, eg `12.0`.

Comment: In any case, I don't use TeeChart, and documentation is hard to find, but I *think* it might be something like this: `TGanttSeries *Series = static_cast<TGanttSeries*>(Chart1->Series[Index]); Series->StartValues[0] = ...; Series->EndValues[0] = ...;`

Comment: Thank you Remy what would i do without you! I already tried it and it don't work. I've got the error message: E2285 Could not find a match for 'TChartValueList::operator =(TDateTime)'. Do you mind to tell me what you use instead of teechart because i also find the documentation lacking and the support is too slow to respond.

Comment: I don't use any charting components. The error means `StartValues` and `EndValues` are declared as `TChartValueList*` pointers, in which case there must be a sub-property to access the actual values, eg `...->StartValues->Value[0] = ...` or similar. Or possibly an `operator*`, eg `(*(...->StartValues))[0] = ...`. I don't have TeeChart hpp files to look at, and the only docs I can find are for .NET

Comment: Thank you as always Remy, i finally found a way, DB Baxter's answer is correct, i forget to set Modified to True after changing values in the Value array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At [teechart.net](http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/vcl/TChartValueList.Modified.html) it's suggested the values can be changed.

> You should set Modified to True after changing values in the Value
>   array directly by code.
>
> Example:
>
> Series1.YValues.Value[12] := 123.45;
>
> Series1.YValues.Modified := True;